# PLSQL query if statement

Tags: oracle

I have a *text* column (let's call it `status`) that can store 3 values:

- `open`,
- `received_complete`,
- `closed`

I would like to create a new *numeric* column (let's call it `stata`) that would satisfy the following rules:

1. If `status` column is `open`, `stata` would be `1`,
2. If `status` column is `received_complete`, `stata` would be `2`,
3. If `status` column is `closed`, `stata` would be `3`.

How do I accomplish this using Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this basically the same question you [asked a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713130/sql-create-new-field-name-from-query-that-populates-value-with-0-or-1)?  It sounds like you just need to make a slight change to the `case` statement that you got in the other question

```
SELECT case when status = 'open' then 1
            when status = 'received_complete' then 2
            when status = 'closesd' then 3
            else null
        end stata
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple "case" expression

```
update table set stata = 
case when status = 'open' then 1
   when status = 'received_complete' then 2
   when status = 'closed' then 3
end
```